# Trim a string to get second word, third word and fourth word in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have two Strings

One is

> String s1 = "I have 1000 dollars";

Second is

> String s2 = "I want my pet";

I need to ONLY get "have" , "1000", "dollars" in s1.
Similarly, I need to ONLY get "want", "my" and "pet" in s2.

I know how to get the "I" using the code

> String newS1 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" "));

Is there a way I can achieve this using substring?

Comment: @fooore do you really need to use substrings? cuz using substring does not work always

Comment: It would be nicer to use substrings, since I saw threads about people using Patterns, .replaceAll() and such.

Comment: `String newS1 = s.substring(s.indexOf(" "), s.lastIndexOf(" "));` does not do what you say it does . . .

Comment: @foooree do you need second and third words in your all strings?

Comment: Yes, I need the second, third and fourth words

Comment: @foooree if it is the case, why do no you use split function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String trimFirstWord(String s) {
    return s.contains(" ") ? s.substring(s.indexOf(' ')).trim() : "";
}
```

Comment: he wants second and third words

Comment: This returns all but the first word - once the quotes on s.contains() are corrected - it doesn't support a character for input.  Also, the trim() isn't really necessary - change `s.indexOf(' ')` to `s.indexOf(' ') + 1` to drop the space after the first word but keep the rest of leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: its fine. I can work with this. if I can remove the first word then I'd be able to use the wordRemovedFirstSpace and use that again.

Comment: it does not even run?!!!!!!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.lang.String.contains

Comment: @foooree it is not right to accept the answer that even does not run. It will be misleading for other who check your question. I do not want you to accept my answer but at least accept the right answer not something that does not run ?!!!!

Comment: I've changed the contains to accept a space string instead of a char. I used trim for the case where there is more than one space between the first and second word. Using indexOf(' ') + 1 can throw an index out of bounds exception if the string is just a space. Also, the question seemed to ask to for a trim first word method, not just just second and third.

Comment: This is what worked for me String removeFirstSpace = s.contains(" ") ? s.substring(s.indexOf(" ")).trim() : "";

Answer (score 4):

If you always want to use second ,third ,and fourth words in any strings you have, I would recommend you to use split functions.

Code:

```
    String s1 = "I have 1000 dollars";
    String[] sp = s1.split(" ");
    System.out.println("second word is " + sp[1]);
    System.out.println("third word is " + sp[2]);
    System.out.println("Fourth words is " +sp[3]);
```

Output:

```
second word is have
third word is 1000
fourth word is dollars
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below rgex to get the second, third, fourth words.

```
^\\S+\\s*(\\S+)\\s*(\\S+)\\s*(\\S+).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sX9fR0/7)

Group index 1 contains the first word, index 2 contains the 2nd word and index 3 contains the third word.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^\\S+\\s*(\\S+)\\s*(\\S+)\\s*(\\S+).*$");
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("I have 1000 dollars");
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3));

}
```

**Output:**

```
have
1000
dollars
```